# Mocking a class with params in constructor

Tags: mocking, moq

I using Moq and have a class like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
   public MyClass (string param1, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] params)
   {
   }
}
```

I want to mock this class in this context:

```
var moqClass = new Mock<MyClass>("text");
```

When I use the `moqClass.Object`, I get an error that the specified constructor was not found.
How can I do this?

Comment: Your constructor can't have a parameter named "params", besides that the whole thing compiles and works for me. Are you getting the error on the "var moqClass" line or on some line you've not included?

Comment: While you can mock classes to override virtual methods, in general most mocks should be of interfaces. With interfaces, there are no constructors so the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Passing `null` for your `params` constructor argument will get past this error:

```
var moqClass = new Mock<MyClass>("text", null);
```